# Series RL Circuits in AC

Tags: ac, dc, design, physics, circuit-design

Could anyone help me with this question I just want to know how the schematic looks like ?

[image]

Comment: The key here is "Series RL Circuit". It is utterly simple if you check your textbook...

Answer (score 1):

"Series RL Circuit":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJltuz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: it won't simulate without a ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

save this text in a file called something`.asc` and you should be able to open it in lt-spice,

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE -144 96 -224 96
WIRE 0 96 -64 96
WIRE -224 144 -224 96
WIRE 0 144 0 96
WIRE -224 256 -224 224
WIRE 0 256 0 224
WIRE 0 256 -224 256
WIRE 0 288 0 256
FLAG 0 288 0
SYMBOL voltage -224 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 10 60)
SYMBOL res -16 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL ind -160 112 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0 Rpar=0
TEXT -258 296 Left 2 !.tran 0 0.083333 0
```

it should look something like this
[image]

Comment: how I can measure the Peak Current of the 5th cycle in the waveform?

Comment: hit the run button and stick the probe on the middle of the inductor, ans oscilloscope display will pop up., you can zoom it by dragging rectangles.

Comment: do you have any idea how I can get the total Circuit Impedance?

Comment: one more qs plz,  how did you calculate the numbers of the (.tran 0 0 .083333 0 )

Comment: double click it and the run parameters dialog opens. 0.0833333 is 5/60 = 1/12  (time in seconds for 5 cycles of 60Hz)

Comment: that directive was made the first time i clicked run.